# how to run code Python to crawl data without using UI Chrome

Tags: python

I have a personal project, which is converting speech to text using the website veed.io, I did it and used selenium to manipulate it, but is there any other way without using the interface? ? I really don't like the import file window every time it pops up, please help me with that. Thank you very much!
Below is my code.

```
import subprocess
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pyautogui
import asyncio

# Đường dẫn đến trình duyệt Chromium
chromium_binary_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Chromium\\Application\\chrome.exe'  # Đường dẫn tới trình duyệt Chromium

# Khởi tạo dịch vụ của Chromium WebDriver
chromium_driver_path = 'C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe'  # Đường dẫn tới Chromium WebDriver
service = Service(executable_path=chromium_driver_path)

# Khởi tạo tùy chọn cho trình duyệt Chromium
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = chromium_binary_path
options.add_argument('--disable-features=AutoUpdate')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

# Chỉ định đường dẫn đến thư mục profile
user_data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Chromium\\User Data\\'
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={user_data_dir}')

# Khởi tạo trình duyệt Chromium với dịch vụ và tùy chọn
folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\video upload'
# Đường dẫn đến thư mục lưu trữ tệp đầu ra
output_folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\output1'
file_names = os.listdir(folder_path)

for file_name in file_names:
    #time.sleep(80)
    # Mở trang web Veed.io (hoặc bất kỳ trang web nào bạn muốn)
    #time.sleep(20)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.veed.io/workspaces")
    # Sử dụng WebDriverWait để chờ cho nút Create Project xuất hiện
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 220)
    create_project_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[action="create"].sc-bJfWxP.JGUMc')))
    create_project_button.click()

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 220)
    upload_file_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="@upload-file"]')))
    upload_file_button.click()

    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)

    async def delay_function():
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
    async def main():
        await delay_function()
    asyncio.run(main())

    pyautogui.write(file_path) 

    async def delay_function():
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
    async def main():
        await delay_function()
    asyncio.run(main())

    pyautogui.press("enter")

    #time.sleep(15)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 220)
    subtitles_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-testid="@editor/subtitles"]')))
    
    async def delay_function():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    async def main():
        await delay_function()
    asyncio.run(main())

    subtitles_button.click()

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 220)
    subtitles_options = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="@editor/subtitles-option/automatic"]')))
    subtitles_options.click()

    #time.sleep(2)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 220)
    subtitles_options_start = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="@editor/subtitles/create-subtitles-button"]')))
    async def delay_function():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    async def main():
        await delay_function()
    asyncio.run(main())
    subtitles_options_start.click()

    try:
        element_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'vb-close-button')))
        print("Thẻ đã được tìm thấy:")
        # Thực hiện click vào thẻ
        element_popup.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Không tìm thấy POP UP:")

    #pyautogui.press("f5")
    element_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2020).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-contents="true"]')))

    span_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@data-text="true"]')
    all_text_content = ""
    #time.sleep(10)
    for span_element in span_elements:
        text_content = span_element.text.strip()
        all_text_content += text_content + '\n'
    # Lấy tên tệp đầu vào mà không có phần mở rộng
    file_name_without_extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]

    # Đặt đường dẫn cho tệp đầu ra trong thư mục lưu trữ tệp đầu ra
    output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, f'{file_name_without_extension}.txt')
    with open(output_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(all_text_content)
    print(all_text_content)
    # Đóng trình duyệt khi đã xử lý xong tệp hiện tại
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Their [robots.txt](https://www.veed.io/robots.txt) file forbids the scraping of that page. They provide an API, you might want to look into using it instead.